# How to use rest API in magento 2 I search a lot but could not find a solution

Tags: magento2, api

I searched on the web but could not find any solution how to use rest API in magento2 please guide me.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/ . This link demonstrate rest and soap both . You can follow this as well

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [this link](https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/). I hope you'll get solution.

> In this post I work through a working example of how to create a new
>   REST web service in Magento 2. My goal is to show how easy it is
>   define a new RESTful service. The examples start with a simple
>   integers, moves on to arrays, then ends with a more complex data type
>   to pass into and return from a service call. This post focusses on
>   JSON, but REST with XML and SOAP are also supported by Magento 2. Full
>   documentation can be found on http://devdocs.magento.com under the
>   “Web Services Developer”.